# MsgController.$inject = ['$scope']

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and want to know what does the below mean:
Why is the word `MsgController` is repeated in the statement below:

```
angular.module('MsgApp', [])
            .controller('MsgController', MsgController);
```

What does this mean:

```
MsgController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Here is the full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='MsgApp'>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function () {
            'use strict';
            angular.module('MsgApp', [])
                .controller('MsgController', MsgController);

            MsgController.$inject = ['$scope'];
            function MsgController($scope) {
                $scope.name = "Dog";
                $scope.stateOfBeing = "hungry";
                $scope.sayMessage = function () {
                    return "Dog like to eat healthy snacks";
                }

                $scope.feedDog = function () {
                    $scope.stateOfBeing = "fed";
                }
            }
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Expressions and Interpolation</h1>
<div ng-controller='MsgController'>
    {{name}} has a message for you:<br/>
    {{sayMessage()}}
    <div>
        <button ng-click="feedDog()">Feed Dog</button>
        <br/>
        <img ng-src="images/dog_{{stateOfBeing}}.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: these are basic questions. Kindly have a look into this https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00. You might get all of your answers here.

Answer (score 1):

```
.controller('MsgController', MsgController);
```

Here , the first parameter indicates the name of the Controller,  2nd parameter indicates the functionality i.e the function which is mapped to the controller.

```
MsgController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

It indicates that $scope is being passed as a dependency to the controller **`MsgController`**.

Comment: is there any benefit of injecting $scope like this way?

Comment: There is no significant advantage, but its one way of injecting depdencies, you could find $inject services being used to inject dependencies in unit testing of the controller.

Comment: There **is** an advantage. If you don't have this line, or don't use `.controller('MsgController', ['$scope', MsgController]);` to declare your controller, then you code will be broken when you try minifying it. It's all explained in the angular documentation for dependency injection: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di. You can also use ng-annotate to insert those instructions for you before minifying.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey you can define like this also**

angular.module('MsgApp', [])
            .controller('MsgController', MsgController);

/**@inject*/

function MsgController($scope){

//do something

}

Use gulp-ng-annotate or grunt-ng-annotate in an automated build task.

Inject /* @ngInject */ prior to any function that has dependencies.